# htaccess 404 issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working with a CMS, and up until today its been fine.

But i have discovered that the mod rewirte only works if the website is in the root directory. If I put the entire CMS into a folder, i get a 404.

Please help!

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6&7=$7 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to add the subfolder to your rewrite rule like this, for all of your rules.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /subfolder/index.php?1=$1 [L]
```

With your configuration apache will search for the index.php file in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Your script is extracting data that are between slashes like:

```
/test1/test2/ transfers into /index.php?1=test1&2=test2
```

but since you started using folder it works like:

```
/folder/test1/test2/ transfers into /index.php?1=folder&2=test1&3=test2
```

so the folder name is breaking your structure, you will need to fix every line with folder name or expression like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/\.]+/([^/\.]+)/?$ /folder/index.php?1=$1 [L]
```

So you will need to fix both regular expression and new path on every line, just replace folder with name of your folder and add **[^/\.]+/** at start

If that doesnt work you may just need to fix regular expression only without adding /folder to the second part of line